# statusFinal value is blank from 9:00 to 9:45

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to show the statusFinal value of the product by comparing two string time values.

Problem is,
StartTimeNames: 9:00 to 9:45, status is blank (statusFinal value is not showing), and statusFinal value displays from 10:00 to the end time.

`_vmModel.keyValuePairs` is a object of viewmodel Dictionary,

`_vmModel.ProductTypesSel` is array of ProductType[] ,

`_vmModel.StartTimeNames` is array of string[]

What's wrong with this code?
Please see image.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
 Dictionary<int, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> keyValuePairs = _vmModel.keyValuePairs;
```

```
foreach (var item in _vmModel.ProductTypesSel)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> temp = keyValuePairs[item.Code];

    for (int i = 0; i < _vmModel.StartTimeNames.Length; i++)
    {
        string filterStartTimeNames = _vmModel.StartTimeNames[i];
        string statusFinal = "";

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> timeValue in temp)
        {
            
            if (filterStartTimeNames == timeValue.Key)
            {
                statusFinal = timeValue.Value;
                Console.WriteLine("LoopCheck Nested Locked Value: " + timeValue.Key);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LoopCheck Nested Not Matched: " + timeValue.Key);
            }
        }
        Label statuslabel = new Label() { Text = statusFinal, WidthRequest = 80 };
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is `_vmModel.keyValuePairs`, `_vmModel.ProductTypesSel`, `_vmModel.StartTimeNames`? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: `_vmModel.keyValuePairs` is a object of viewmodel Dictionary, `_vmModel.ProductTypesSel` is array of ProductType[] ,  `_vmModel.StartTimeNames` is array of string[]  ;   I'm trying to update with more details. @KlausGütter

Comment: I can't understand your question clearly. Do you mean the `statusFinal value` from 9:00 to 9:45 were lost?

Comment: Yes on 9:00 to 9:45 `statusFinal value` is not showing @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: It is start showing from 10:00 to till Endtime 20:15 @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Can you check if the `statusFinal value ` is null in the viewmodel from 9:00 to 9:45?

Comment: And what is the content of keyValuePairs, ProductTypesSel and StartTimeNames?

Comment: `statusFinal = timeValue.Value;` Value is showing 10:00 @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: but `_vmModel.StartTimeNames` array start from 9:00 @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: So just add a break point at `if (filterStartTimeNames == timeValue.Key)` to check  if `statusFinal = timeValue.Value;` excute or not when the loop begin.

Comment: But the first time should be `9:00` according to your description.

Comment: Sorry, 9:00 is coming after excute, it's going to else part @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: So there is something wrong in the  `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

Comment: Yes maybe , `statusFinal = timeValue.Value;` is showing 9:00 @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249856/discussion-between-liyun-zhang-msft-and-raj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, there must be some logic mistakes in your code. The most simple and direct method to deal with the problem is debugging to find which line code has the result you didn't want.

Just add a break point at `foreach (var item in _vmModel.ProductTypesSel)`. When the loop begin, run the code step by step and check the variable's value every time.

By checking the result of each line code is same as predicted, you can find where the problem is and resolve it.

Comment: I got my mistake. `filterStartTimeNames value is 9:00` and `timeValue.Key value is 09:00 `  ;  both time formats are not equivalent.  I fixed it. Thank you; @LiyunZhang-MSFT